# How to change selected index of tabbarcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UICollectionView` and a `UIContainerView` in a `UIViewController`. The embedded view of container view is `UITabBarController`. I need to change the item in tabBarController according to selection in the `UICollectionView`. How to achieve this?

Comment: A controller is embedded in container view using segue. You can use prepareForSegue to get the controller.

Comment: Can i call the performSegue from didselect of collectionview with indexpath.row as sender and setting selected index of tabbarcontroller as sender value? Is this what you mean @KeshuR.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1:** Declare a varaible of type `YourTabBarController`

**Step 2**: Go to the storyboard and click on the segue that connects container view and the tab bar controller. Give it the identifier as "`tabBar`" or whatever you want. I have used `tabBar` as an identifier in the below example. Then you need to call the `prepareForSegue` method and you can get your Tab Bar Controller from here. Then we will assign the value to our `yourTabController`

**Step3:** In your `didSelectItemAt` method, now you can change the selected index value.

Thats It!

```
// step1 

private var yourTabController : YourTabBarController!

//step2 

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let tbc = segue.destination as? YourTabBarController, segue.identifier == "tabBar" {
     self.yourTabController = tbc
}

//step3 

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.yourTabController.selectedIndex = 1 // change it accordingly
}
```

Comment: Actually, what is happening there in prepareForSegue method? And why do we create a variable of TabBarController and assigning it inside prepare func?

Comment: When your View controller appears, the container view calls this prepareForSegue method to add the tab bar controller in container view. There can be multiple segues from a view controller to other. Thats why we place a check if `segue.identifier == "tabBar",` then we assign the value of the segue.destination to your `self.yourTabController`. So now you have access to your tab bar controller and you can access all its properties.

Comment: Great. All I was looking for is how to access the properties of tabBarController. Now got it. Thanks again.